# NullPointerException when trying to detect shakes

Tags: android, service, android-intent, shake

I'm getting a NullPointerException in my application when trying to detect a shake.

In my application I have a service running in the background, and an activity that calls the method cameraIntent().

```
public class Run1 extends Activity implements Shaker.Callback {
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
private Uri fileUri;
private static final String TAG = Shaker.class.getSimpleName();
final Handler handle = new Handler();
Shaker shaker;
shakeCameraService shakecamera;


public void miThread() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            handle.post(proceso);
        }
    };
    t.start();

}

public final Runnable proceso = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {         
        cameraIntent();


    }
};



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.e("ONCREATE RUN1 ", "ONCREATE RUN1");
    startService(new Intent(this, shakeCameraService.class));       

}

public void cameraIntent() {
    shaker = new Shaker(this, 5.0d, 500, this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to
                                                        // // save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name
    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (fileUri != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Result ok");
                Log.e(TAG, "Image saved to:\n" + fileUri);
                Log.e(TAG, "Image path:\n" + fileUri.getPath());
                // uri.getLastPathSegment()
                // if store
                // in folder
            }

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "RESULT CANCELED");

        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }

}

private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("ShakerCam", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public void shakingStarted() {
    miThread();

}

public void shakingStopped() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is my service

```
public class shakeCameraService extends Service implements Shaker.Callback {
Run1 run1;
Shaker shaker =null;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    shaker = new Shaker(this, 5.0d, 500, this);
    Log.e("ONCREATE SERVICE", "ONCREATE SERVICE");

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    shaker = new Shaker(this, 5.0d, 500, this);
    Log.e("onStart Servicio ", "onStart Servicio ");
}

@Override
public void shakingStarted() {
    shaker = new Shaker(this, 5.0d, 500, this);
    Log.e("shakingstrated SERVICE", "shakingstrated SERVICE");
    run1.cameraIntent();

}


@Override
public void shakingStopped() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



}
```

The error is logcat me back then! And nose like really solve this problem!

```
04-19 23:26:30.788: ERROR/ONCREATE RUN1(356): ONCREATE RUN1
04-19 23:26:30.808: DEBUG/onCReate RUN1(356): antes de llamar a shakingstrated
04-19 23:26:30.808: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(356): Shutting down VM
04-19 23:26:30.808: WARN/dalvikvm(356): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-19 23:26:30.822: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sebastian.shakeCam/com.sebastian.shakeCam.Run1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at com.sebastian.shakeCam.Run1.onCreate(Run1.java:57)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-19 23:26:30.842: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(356):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Sebastian, please indicate line 57 in your class Run1. I tried to copy paste it to check for line 57, but the line numbering must have changed in either your or my copy paste. - Anyway, start at that line.

Comment: hi thanks for responding. On line 57 the method called shakecameraservice.shakingstarted () to test the error that I was on the phone. But when I run it from the cell with logcat shoot me an error like that! Sorry for my English I speak Spanish and use google translate! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onStart(...)` method of `Service` is deprecated.

You should implement `onStartCommand (...)` instead. See the docs for [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).

I'm not sure if it will fix your problem though.

Comment: I changed that part of the code by adding this method but the problem remains! Someone comes up with a way to fix this?